# How to create organizational chart in oracle apex

Tags: treeview, oracle-apex, organizational-chart

I am trying to create an organizational chart using [Apex D3 Organization Chart Plugin](https://github.com/RonnyWeiss/Apex-D3-Organization-Chart). But it is only able to show the name of the employee. I can't show designation, department or employee image. Can someone please help me? How can I show images of each item name with some more information? Secondly, Hyperlinks work on leaf node only (Child node mentioned in image). Please guide how to add hyperlinks on parent node as well.
[image]

Actually, I want to design an expandable organizational chart, something like the image below. Can anyone mention if any plugins are available or some dynamic HTML code? Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Are you saying that you're using an existing plugin to render the application org chart ? What plugin is it ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie, I am using [Apex-D3-Organization-Chart](https://github.com/RonnyWeiss/Apex-D3-Organization-Chart) plugin. I want to extend its functionality or please suggest if there is some better plugin available or some dynamic pl/sql code.

Comment: That is a non-commercial plugin. You can clone it and change it yourself to suit your own needs. Since you are only looking for small changes that is probably easiest and fastest. I have not done much plugin work but that is how I usually started (copy an existing plugin). I'm not familiar with what plugins are available.

Comment: @KoenLostrie thanks for your response. Actually, I am not that much matured to update the plugin files accordingly. So, that's why I am looking for help.

Comment: Yeah sorry to be so blunt but... you're probably on your own. Chances that someone has done exactly that are very small. Plugins is a lot of custom work, I doubt anyone is going to step in and do it for you :)